# SFML - sprite not centering properly

Tags: c++, sprite, sfml

I have this image of size 256 × 256 that I want to center, but for some odd reason it isn't working.

[image: Image of game running]

As you can see it's not centered. Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    int w = 720;
    int h = 360;
```

Some other code:

```
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(w, h), "RPG Game", sf::Style::Default);
sf::Texture texture;
texture.loadFromFile("WalkCycle.png");
sf::Texture inventory;
inventory.loadFromFile("Inventory.png");
sf::Sprite player(texture);
sf::Sprite inventorySprite(inventory);

sf::Vector2u textureSize = texture.getSize();
textureSize.x /= 9;
textureSize.y /= 4;

player.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0, 0, textureSize.x, textureSize.y));
player.setOrigin(textureSize.x/2, textureSize.y/2);
player.setPosition(w/2, h/2);
inventorySprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0, 0, 256, 256));
inventorySprite.setOrigin(256/2, 256/2);
inventorySprite.setPosition(w/2, h/2);

//Game loop

if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::E))
        inventoryOpen = true;

if(inventoryOpen)
        window.draw(inventorySprite);
```

Ignore the player sprite. I'm having a problem with the 'InventorySprite'.

It's my first time posting, so excuse me if I forgot to include something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you Need to do is to set the texture position in relation to the window width an height. Here the pseudo Code:

```
texturePosition.X = (windowWidth - textureWidth) / 2;
texturePosition.Y = (windowHeight - textureHeight) / 2;
```

Comment: Did that but it now places it in the top left corner...

inventorySprite.setPosition((w - inventory.getSize().x)/2, (h - inventory.getSize().y)/2);

Comment: That would mean it places it at 0,0 Position. You need to debug this particular line to grasp why it returns 0

Comment: I found the problem. Apparently the texture had some empty space around it which caused the calculations to be wrong. Thanks for your help